# Get syntax highlighting for specific file in Emacs?

Tags: bash, emacs, syntax-highlighting

I have created the file `~/.bashrc__common`, which I source from `~/.bashrc`, and I would like this file to be syntax highlighted just like other shell scripts when I open it in Emacs. I have added the following line to my `~/.emacs` file:

`(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.bashrc__common\\." . sh-mode) auto-mode-alist))`

However, the file is still not syntax highlighted when I open it (but I don't fully understand why this line looks as it does and I'm not sure it is correctly formatted). Besides, `~/.bashrc` seems to be syntax highlighted automatically, even though I haven't told Emacs to do that. Why?

Comment: You can insert `# -*- mode: shell-script -*-` to the file itself.

Comment: @choroba That works, but I consider it a workaround, and it is one extra line that I need to have in there that I would like to not need to have. And I want to learn how to add syntax highlighting the way I inteded it, so I can do it for other files as well in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The line you added to your ~/.emacs file is not correctly formatted. In order to properly add a new file extension to the auto-mode-alist, you need to use the "add-to-list" function. The correct line would be:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\.bashrc__common\." . sh-mode))
```

As for why ~/.bashrc is automatically syntax highlighted, it is likely because it is a common file name for shell scripts and Emacs has a built-in rule to automatically use the sh-mode major mode for files with that name. You can check the existing rules in the auto-mode-alist by using the "describe-variable" function in the Emacs minibuffer